# How does Beautiful Soup extract class attribute values?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I use beautifulsoup to extract multiple attribute values of class, but `['fa', 'fa-address-book-o']` is not the result I want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<i class='fa fa-address-book-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

h2 = soup.select("i")

print(h2[0]['class'])
```

**I want the effect to be as follows:**

```
fa fa-address-book-o
```

Comment: `' '.join(h2[0]['class'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

join all the elements in your list, and put a space between them

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<i class='fa fa-address-book-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

h2 = soup.select("i")

print(' '.join(h2[0]['class']))
```